# Post Gitilesplugin-2.10 installation in gerrit unable to see Browse option

Tags: plugins, gerrit

**My Environment:-**

```
My Gerrit Version is -2.10.2
Gitilesplugin-gitiles-stable Version -2.10 - (In Gerrit under Plugin category installed status shows Enabled).
```

**Problem:** I have installed Gitiles plugin and restarted my gerrit application service. After gerrit service restart, I am unable to see “**Browse**” option  under **Repository Browser** category. Whereas i am able to browse under plugin menu. Means if I can click over installed gitiles plugin, then I am able to browse the repository & branches etc..(A separate link New-Window [http://our-gerrit-hostname/gerrit/plugins/gitiles/] opens from here i can browse it).

Plugin I have downloaded from http://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/job/plugin-gitiles-stable-2.10/gitiles.jar

Also I have tried adding below in my gerrit.config file. Still Browse option not showing in gerrit Web.

```
[Gitiles]
 type = custom  linkname = gitiles 
 url = plugins/gitiles/ 
 revision = ${project}/+/${commit} 
 project = ${project} branch = ${project}/+/${branch}
 filehistory = ${project}/+log/${branch}/${file}
```

Do I need to configure/enable anything else? Kindly advise me, As I could not find guide for the same.

Comment: url = plugins/gitiles/ i tried with url = gerrit/plugins/gitiles/ as well still not working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the section in `gerrit.config` file from `gitiles` to `gitweb` And also I have added below lines.

```
file = ${project}+${commit}/${file}
roottree = ${project}
```

Now it is working perfectly as expected.